# How do I Block a Port on all IPS, except 1?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables, ports

how do i block a port on all IP's except 1?

say I have IP's:

192.168.1
192.168.2

ex: how would i only allow port 21 on 192.168.1 through IP tables or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` supports the `-d` parameter for this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.0.2 --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j DROP
```

This will allow traffic from all sources to IP `192.168.0.2` on port 21. The second line blocks all traffic on port 21. iptables works on a "first match" principle.